# extract tags not having sub elements

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a web page which is something like this

```
<p> Content </p> 
........... 
.......... 

<p> Other content    
      <b> Use link <b>    
      <h3> some text <h3> 
</p> 
........... 
........... and some other elements starting with <p> tag having 
different sub-elements inside it
```

What I want to do is to extract text of only those `<p>` tags which doesnt have any sub elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposes solution is correct when using XSLT. As you tagged this just with xpath, here is the XPath version:

```
//p[count(*) = 0]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just checking if there is one, is often faster than count:

```
//p[not(*)]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:if test="count(*) = 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will print the value of p tags only if the node have no other tags inside it.